# Programmatically capturing AJAX traffic with headless Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

Chrome officially supports running the browser in headless mode (including programmatic control via the Puppeteer API and/or the CRI library).

I've searched through the documentation, but I haven't found how to programmatically capture the AJAX traffic from the instances (ie. start an instance of Chrome from code, navigate to a page, and access the background response/request calls & raw data (*all from code* not using the developer tools or extensions).

Do you have any suggestions or examples detailing how this could be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/dusk-testing-an-ajax-request-performed-by-a-modal-onscroll-event ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**

As @Alejandro pointed out in the comment, `resourceType` is a function and the return value is lowercased

```
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.resourceType() === 'xhr')
    // do something
});
```

**Original answer**

Puppeteer's API makes this really easy:

```
page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.resourceType === 'XHR')
    // do something
});
```

You can also intercept requests with `setRequestInterception`, but it's not needed in this example if you're not going to modify the requests.

There's an [example of intercepting image requests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/block-images.js) that you can adapt.

`resourceType`s are defined [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/2817130fe099a7431e98c20ce1f44c6e547d4ca9/docs/api.md#requestresourcetype).

Comment: Perfect . Just a few notes, `resourceType` is a function and the return value is lowercased, so it should be `if (request.resourceType() === 'xhr')`.

Comment: will this fetch the ajax calls that page sending on document.ready() function?
I cant see them

Answer (score 4):

I finally found how to do what I wanted. It can be done with `chrome-remote-interface` (CRI), and `node.js`. I'm attaching the minimal code required.

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

(async function () {

    // you need to have a Chrome open with remote debugging enabled
    // ie. chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
    const protocol = await CDP({port: 9222});

    const {Page, Network} = protocol;
    await Page.enable();
    await Network.enable(); // need this to call Network.getResponseBody below

    Page.navigate({url: 'http://localhost/'}); // your URL

    const onDataReceived = async (e) => {
        try {
            let response = await Network.getResponseBody({requestId: e.requestId})
            if (typeof response.body === 'string') {
                console.log(response.body);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex.message)
        }
    }

    protocol.on('Network.dataReceived', onDataReceived)
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Puppeteer's listeners could help you capture xhr response via `response` and `request` event.

You should check wether `request.resourceType()` is `xhr` or `fetch` first.

```
        listener = page.on('response', response => {
            const isXhr = ['xhr','fetch'].includes(response.request().resourceType())
            if (isXhr){
                console.log(response.url());
                response.text().then(console.log)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const pageClient = page["_client"];
pageClient.on("Network.responseReceived", event => {
  if (~event.response.url.indexOf('/api/chart/rank')) {
    console.log(event.response.url);
    pageClient.send('Network.getResponseBody', {
      requestId: event.requestId
    }).then(async response => {
      const body = response.body;
      if (body) {
        try {
          const json = JSON.parse(body);

        }
        catch (e) {
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on("request", async request => {
  request.continue();
});
await page.goto('http://www.example.com', { timeout: 0 });
```